# How to get the following transition/animation effect in App Bar dropdown menu?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, material-design, android-menu

I'm developing a material design app & I want [this](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage) effect when I click on the menu option or the three dots on the side of ActionBar/Toolbar.

The effect I want is at the last of '[usage](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-usage)' section & just above the '[menu items](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html#menus-menu-items)' section. It is labeled as 'App bar dropdown'.

Answer (score 0):

The 'three dots' is commonly called the 'overflow' menu on Android, and knowing the terminology will improve your search results.

[CodePath](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Defining-The-ActionBar) has an example on using the Toolbar as ActionBar. It will be helpful to read the whole page, because it explains the history of both Toolbar and ActionBar. The section [Using toolbar as ActionBar](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Defining-The-ActionBar#using-toolbar-as-actionbar) is particularly relevant to your question.

In your MainActivity onCreate method:

```
// Set a ToolBar to replace the ActionBar.
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Your MainActivity will override the onCreateOptionsMenu and inflate your menu resource file:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And you will define a menu resource file: 
/res/menu/menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

The 'showAsAction' attribute tells Android to only display this menu item in the overflow menu (never as an action on the toolbar).

Comment: But this didn't answer my question.

Comment: Are you are referring to the 'ripple' effect on the selection of overflow menu? This has to do with your application theme.

Comment: This is a feature of Lollipop. If you extend from a Material theme or AppCompat theme (using the Design Support Library) you will get ripple effects by default.